Excel macro - create new worksheet and paste values
I have a workbook with multiple worksheets that are protected, I need to copy and paste the values from a named worksheet into a new and separate workbook. Lets say one worksheet is called 'Property'
What I have found so far copies the source so needed the protection removing, I can do this but cannot then automate the protection being re-applied to the original sheet instead it protects the new workbook.
Sub CopyDisposals()

    ' Declare variables
    Dim sourceWs As Worksheet
    Dim newWb As Workbook
    
    ' Set the source worksheet you want to copy from the active workbook
    Set sourceWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Disposals")
    
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "*****"

    ' Copy the entire source worksheet to a new workbook
    sourceWs.Copy
    Set newWb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    ' Activate the copied worksheet in the new workbook
    newWb.Sheets(1).Activate
    
    ' Copy the used range of the active sheet to clipboard
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    
    ' Paste the copied data as values into the active sheet starting at cell "A1"
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    ' Clear clipboard to remove the dashed line around the copied range
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    ActiveSheet.Protect "*****"
    

End Sub


Try to avoid using ActiveSheet. Instead assign a variable to each worksheet

Sub CopyDisposals()

    ' Declare variables
    Dim sourceWs As Worksheet
    Dim newWs As Worksheet
    Dim newWb As Workbook
    
    ' Set the source worksheet you want to copy from the active workbook
    Set sourceWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Disposals")
    
    sourceWs.Unprotect "*****"

    ' Create a new workbook
    Set newWb = Workbooks.add
    Set newWS = newWb.Sheets(1)
    
    ' Copy the used range of the source worksheet to the new worksheet
    newWS.Range(sourceWs.UsedRange.Address).value = sourceWs.UsedRange.value
    
    sourceWs.Protect "*****"
    
End Sub

(Note, I have not tested this, but it should give you an idea of where to go
